# Running a bat file in background in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, background

I need to run a bat file in background in windows.
I have tried using the`START` command.

The problem is, I connect to this machine remotely & if I log off, then the process gets killed.

Is there any way to keep a bat file running even after I log off from the remote machine?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Srvany: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890

RunAsService: http://runasservice.sourceforge.net/

Nssm: http://nssm.cc/

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the bat file from a Windows service (using a service account) you will be able to log off and have the bat file execute in the background.

This walkthrough might be handy 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx