# Execute Batch File without Command line visible

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have to run a batch file without showing the command line but the Command line keeps on popping up. This is my code:

```
@echo off
:SAMPLE
cd /d C:
md %RANDOM%
cd /d D:
md %RANDOM%
cd /d E:
md %RANDOM%
goto SAMPLE
```

Comment: What do you mean with command line? A prompt? Unlikely, I guess. The executed statements? Possible, if you have something preceding the `@echo off` so that it doesn't work. The console window? Definitely, but you can't solve that with a batch file alone, then.

Comment: that's the whole code of my batch file. and i mean, the command prompt window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a CMD or BAT in silent mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411247/running-a-cmd-or-bat-in-silent-mode)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Solution-1**:

Save your code in a batch file lets say `My.bat`

Create a VBScript file lets say `Master.vbs` and call your `My.bat` file within it.

Lets assume your batch file is at `C:\Test\My.bat` then:

**Master.vbs:**

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Test\My.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

It'll run your batch file in invisible/hidden mode.

**Solution-2**:

If at all possible, modify the batch file to run whatever program with the `start` command. By default, `start` returns immediately without waiting for the program to exit, so the batch file will continue to run and, presumably, exit immediately. Couple that with modifying your shortcut to run the batch file minimized, and you’ll only see the taskbar flash without even seeing a window onscreen.

Answer (score 3):

The following sample code works

```
start cmd /c "some command && exit 0"
```

The trick is => && exit 0

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for. For me it still launches the command window, but at least that window doesn't show terminal output and I can close it without stopping the process started by `some command`. It looks like taking the extra step of starting the command like `start /min cmd ...` has the added benefit of minimizing the command line window to begin with, but still doesn't get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the redirect in the following way:

```
@echo off
:SAMPLE
cd /d C:
md %RANDOM% >nul 2>&1
cd /d D:
md %RANDOM% >nul 2>&1
cd /d E:
md %RANDOM% >nul 2>&1
goto SAMPLE
```

Got this from: [Suppress command line output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262708/suppress-command-line-output)

Comment: what do you mean by "command line"?  do you mean the command prompt window?

Comment: yeah. the batch file should run without it showing the cmd window.

Comment: you can minimize the command prompt window from whatever you're calling the script from like `start /min mybat.bat`, but as Joey pointed out above, there's no other way to do it internally

Comment: you can try to run is as a service:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902282/running-a-bat-file-in-background-in-windows